# What is the fifth possible value of \protect?

Tags: latex-base, protected-macro

Section ["11.4 Robust Commands and \protect" of source2e.pdf (File d: ltdefns.dtx Date: 2020/02/27 Version v1.5g)](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/base/source2e.pdf#subsection.11.4) says that `\protect` can have one of **five** possible "values" but lists only **four** of them:

1. `\relax`
2. `\string`
3. `\noexpand`
4. `\@unexpandable@protect` → `\noexpand\protect\noexpand`

What is the fifth/not listed value?

Why is it not listed?

Answer (score 8):

**Update** The documentation has been fixed for the next release to say **four**, only took 26 years after the code change to bring the documentation into line.

---

Just below the quoted line you see

```
% \changes{1.1c}{1994/05/18}
%     {(ASAJ) Renamed the commands, and removed
%       one which is no longer needed.}
```

which explains why the list is one short, now I'm trying to recall what that was. I have a suspicion it was `\noexpand\noexpand\noexpand` but I'd need to check...

Yes the LaTeX2.09 source (`latex.tex`) uses  `\noexpand\noexpand\noexpand` in for example

```
\def\label#1{\@bsphack\if@filesw {\let\thepage\relax
   \def\protect{\noexpand\noexpand\noexpand}%
```

Comment: It looks like it was redefined to `\@empty` in `\patterns` and `\hyphenation` at some point, but that appears to have been commented out (§20.4.2).

Comment: I think `\noexpand\noexpand\noexpand` was replaced with `\noexpand\protect\noexpand`

Comment: means we should change the docu to say 4

Answer (score 8):

I have source2e.pdf **Date: 2004/02/20** Version 1.3g in my archive.

It says:

> The method LaTeX uses for making fragile commands robust is to precede them with `\protect`. This can have one of five possible values:
>
> - `\relax`, for normal typesetting. So `\protect\foo` will execute `\foo`.
> - `\string`, for writing to the screen. So `\protect\foo` will write `\foo`.
> - `\noexpand`, for writing to a file. So `\protect\foo` will write `\foo` followed by a space.
> - `\@unexpandable@protect`, for writing a moving argument to a file. So `\protect\foo` will write `\protect\foo` followed by a space. This value is also used inside `\edefs`, `\marks` and other commands which evaluate their arguments fully.
> - `\@unexpandable@noexpand`, for performing a deferred write inside an `\edef`. So `\protect\foo` will write `\foo` followed by a space. If you want `\protect\foo` to be written, you should use `\@unexpandable@protect`. **(Removed as never used).**
>
> These commands are used for setting `\protect` inside `\edefs`.
> 192 `\def\@unexpandable@protect{\noexpand\protect\noexpand}`
> 193 `%\def\@unexpandable@noexpand{\noexpand\noexpand\noexpand}`